# How give touch position for particle systems

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How give touch position for particle systems,
I need particle systems follow touch move,

please advise me that something

this script is attached on particle system

```
    void Update () {
    transform.position = new Vector2 (Input.GetTouch (0).position.x, Input.GetTouch (0).position.y);
}
```

Comment: Read "How to make a question" and welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: ok that is wrong ?

Comment: Write what you have tried or more details ....

Comment: I edited, its ok ?

Comment: that's not a script, it's a single line of code. Also, tell us what your code is doing currently.

Comment: This code is in the file on the particle, at the moment nothing is happening, but I need that for touching the particles take the coordinates of the finger

Comment: I don't generally develop for touch devices but I would imagine that you need to translate touch's pixel position to world space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Camera cam = Camera.Main;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            Vector2 touchPos = Input.GetTouch(0).Position;
            transform.position = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touchPos.x, touchPos.y, 0));
        }
    }
```

This work any better?

Comment: I use this cod `void Update () {
  if (Input.touchCount > 0) { 
   if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
    
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.touches[0].position);
    
    pos.z = transform.position.z;
    transform.position = pos;
   }
  }`